# How can I find the rest of a word from a string within it in PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, scraper

Let's say I have a page I want to scrape for words with "ice" in them, how can I do this easily? I see a lot of scrapers breaking things down into source code, but I don't need this. I just need something that searches through the plain text on the webpage.

Edit: I basically need something to search for .jpeg and find the entire file name. (it is in plain text on the website, not hidden in a tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that matches the following is a word with `ice` in it:

```
/(\w*)ice(\w*)/i
```

(Do note that [`\w`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand) matches `0-9` and `_` too. The following might give better results: `/\b.*?ice\b.*?/i`)

---

**UPDATE**
To match file names (must not contain whitespace):

```
/\S+\.jpeg/i
```

[Example](http://www.ideone.com/odqRD):

```
<?php
$str = 'Picture of me: 238484534.jpeg and someone else img-of-someone.jpeg here';
$cnt = preg_match_all('/\S+\.jpeg/i', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an example of how to use this?

Comment: @phpf See update. (BTW, consider using `jpe?g` instead if you need to match both `.jpeg` and `.jpg`.)

Comment: Um, I have one more question! How can I add more extensions to that snippet?

Comment: @phpf `/\S+\.(jpe?g|gif|png)/i` will match `.jpeg`, `.jpg`, `.gif`, and `.png`.

Answer (score 0):

Some regex use will be needed for this. Below I use PCRE http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php and the function preg_match http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

```
<?php

$html = <<<EOF
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>List of files:
        <ul>
            <li>test1.jpeg</li>
            <li>test2.jpeg</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
EOF;
$matches = array();
$count = preg_match_all("([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+\.jpeg)", $html, $matches);
if (count($matches) > 1) {
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($matches); $i++) {
        print "Filename: {$matches[$i]}\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.do u want to read the word inside the HTML tags too like attribute,textname ?
2.Or only the visible part of the webpage ?

for#1 : solutions are simple and already there as mentioned in other answers.

for#2:
Use PHP DOMDOCUMENT class, and extract and search in innerHTML only.
documentation here :

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

see this for example:

[PHP DOMDocument stripping HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85520/php-domdocument-stripping-html-tags)

Comment: I basically want to find a word from a string written in plain text. The url's are written on the page, so I want to grab the entire file name from an extension (e.g. "Picture of me: 238484534.jpeg" when I search for .jpeg I get the entire file name, 238484534.jpeg, into an array)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
preg_match_all('/\w*ice\w*/', 'abc icecream lice', $matches);

print_r($matches);
```