# PHP DOMXPath problem

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$res = $xpath->query(".//*[@id='post2679883']/tr[2]/td[2]/div[2]");
foreach( $res as $obj ) {
    var_dump($obj->nodeValue);
}
```

I need to take all the items in the id with the word "post".

Example:

```
<div id="post2242424">trarata</div>
<div id="post114525">trarata</div>
<div id="post8568686">trarata</div>
```

Question number two:
I need to get this elements with HTML tags, but `$obj->nodeValu`e returns text without html tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the xpath function [`starts-with`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with) to filter the nodes in your XPath if all the nodes you want start with "post". For example;

```
$xpath->query(".//*[starts-with(@id, 'post')]/tr[2]/td[2]/div[2]");
```

For the second part, I think has been answered already - [PHP DOMDocument stripping HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85520/php-domdocument-stripping-html-tags/85563#85563)