# Getting tags in DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I'm trying to get the HTML markup of a table in a page:

```
$new_dom = new DOMDocument();

$table = '';

$nodesTable = $this->dom->getElementsbyTagName("table");

foreach($nodesTable as $nodeTable){
    $color = $nodeTable->getAttribute('bordercolordark');
    if ($color == '#73BAFF') {
        $table = $nodeTable;
    }
}

$new_dom->appendChild($table);

echo $new_dom->saveHTML();
```

Here is somepage.html:

```
<html>
<table>
    <tr> <td> 10 </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> 10 </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> 10 </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> 10 </td> </tr>
</table>

<table border="1" cellpadding="0" width="500" bordercolorlight="#ACD6FF" bordercolordark="#73BAFF" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" bgcolor="#73BAFF"> </td>
        <td colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#ACD6FF"> Element 1 </td>
        <td colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#ACD6FF"> Element 2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="50" align="center" bgcolor="#ACD6FF"> 50 </td>
        <td width="50" align="center" bgcolor="#ACD6FF"> 50 </td>
        <td width="50" align="center" bgcolor="#ACD6FF"> 50 </td>
        <td width="50" align="center" bgcolor="#ACD6FF"> 50 </td>
        <td width="50" align="center" bgcolor="#ACD6FF"> 50 </td>
        <td width="50" align="center" bgcolor="#ACD6FF"> 50 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ACD6FF" width="155" align="center"> Row 1</td>
        <td bgcolor="#ACD6FF" width="45" align="center"> 30 </td>
        <td align="center"> 50 </td>
        <td align="center"> 50 </td>
        <td align="center"> 50 </td>
        <td align="center"> 50 </td>
        <td align="center"> 50 </td>
        <td align="center"> 50 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ACD6FF" width="155" align="center"> Row 2</td>
        <td bgcolor="#ACD6FF" width="45" align="center"> 30 </td>
        <td align="center"> 60 </td>
        <td align="center"> 60 </td>
        <td align="center"> 60 </td>
        <td align="center"> 60 </td>
        <td align="center"> 60 </td>
        <td align="center"> 60 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ACD6FF" width="155" align="center"> Row 3</td>
        <td bgcolor="#ACD6FF" width="45" align="center"> 30 </td>
        <td align="center"> 70 </td>
        <td align="center"> 70 </td>
        <td align="center"> 70 </td>
        <td align="center"> 70 </td>
        <td align="center"> 70 </td>
        <td align="center"> 70 </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr> <td> 10 </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> 10 </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> 10 </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> 10 </td> </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr> <td> 10 </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> 10 </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> 10 </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> 10 </td> </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

$new_dom just outputs \n instead of HTML markup. I tried looking at this answer: [PHP DOMDocument stripping HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85520/php-domdocument-stripping-html-tags), but appending the table this way didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Wrong Document Error'
```

So you cannot move nodes from one document to another... If you want to do that, you have to use [importNode()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) with the `deep` flag.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('x.html');
$new_dom = new DOMDocument();

$table = '';

$nodesTable = $dom->getElementsbyTagName("table");

foreach($nodesTable as $nodeTable){
    $color = $nodeTable->getAttribute('bordercolordark');
    if ($color == '#73BAFF') {
        $table = $new_dom->importNode($nodeTable, true);
    }
}

$new_dom->appendChild($table);

echo $new_dom->saveHTML();
```

This imports only the table element, but not the children...

*note: I'd disable the entity loader in your case `libxml_disable_entity_loader(true);`. I am not sure whether XEE attacks work with `loadHTML()` too, but just for the sake of security.*