# Find nth word/element of string and replace it

Tags: php, substr

I have long unordered list (`<ul>`) which i need to divide to three columns. I have something like this:

```
$num = substr_count($ul, '<li>')/3;
$sep = round($num, 0);
```

...and now i need to find nth element ($sep) of $ul and replace it.

`<li>` to `</ul><ul><li>`

EDIT:

My list look like this:

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
</ul>
```

...and i want like this:

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: place your html part; source_string,replace_string,search_string,

Comment: Paste your input HTML

Comment: If you can get away with just using CSS then take a look at [column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)

Comment: column-count is great but not in this case because it threats all elements as text and one list element could be in two columns (half in one and half in another). I don't want it that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this solution:

```
$ul = '<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li></ul>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $ul);
$liList = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li');
$liValues = array();
foreach ($liList as $li) {
    $liValues[] = $li->c14n();
}

$num = count($liValues) / 3;
$size = round($num+1);

$i = 0;
$list = '';

foreach ($liValues as $listItem) {

    if ($i !== 0 && $i % $size === 0) {
        $list.= '</ul><ul>';
    }

    $list.= $listItem;

    $i++;
}

echo '<ul>'.html_entity_decode(str_replace(array('</br>', '</img>'), '', $list)).'</ul>';
```

Answer (score 2):

I always prefer to use native functions for parsing and manipulating HTML, in this case [PHP's DOM classes](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

```
$ul = "<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li></ul>";

// Import our existing list
$input = new DOMDocument;
$input->loadHTML($ul);

$output = new DOMDocument;

$num = substr_count($ul, '<li>') / 3;
$size = round($num);

$i = 0;

foreach ($input->getElementsByTagName('li') as $listItem) {
    // If we've reached our boundary (or are at the start of the list), add a new UL
    if ($i % $size === 0) {
        $list = $output->createElement('ul');
        $output->appendChild($list);
    }

    // Append our list item to the current list
    $list->appendChild($output->createElement('li', $listItem->nodeValue));

    $i++;
}

echo $output->saveHTML();

// <ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul><ul><li>3</li><li>4</li></ul><ul><li>5</li><li>6</li></ul>
```

Comment: It works great! Small workaround to utf-8:
`$input->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($ul, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));`

Comment: This is much cleaner than mine

Comment: Ok - this works great but it strips all html tags inside list elements. How i can avoid that?

Comment: The answer I posted doesn't strip tags, try it out. You can also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85520/php-domdocument-stripping-html-tags)

Comment: Yep, exactly. Annoyingly, there isn't a very nice way to get the inner HTML of a `DOMNode` in PHP, so you need to use a helper. I was going to link [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286362/php-dom-get-nodevalue-html-without-stripping-tags) instead, but it's more or less identical.

Answer (score 1):

This will get an unordered list as HTML, divide it in three ULs, and spit it back:

```
<?php
$ul = "<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
</ul>";
function divideUl($ul) {
    $ulArray = explode("\n", $ul);
    array_pop($ulArray);
    array_shift($ulArray);
    $num = substr_count($ul, '<li>')/3;
    $sep = round($num);
    $string = "<ul>";
    foreach ($ulArray as $i => $li) {
        if ($i % $sep === 0 && $i !== 0) $string .= "</ul>";
        if ($i % $sep === 0 && $i !== 0) $string .= "<ul>";
        $string .= $li;
    }
    $string .= "</ul>";
    return $string;
}
echo divideUl($ul);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/lqCFF)